# Use of fft on sound using Julia

Tags: audio, julia, fft

I have some code in Julia I've just wrote:

```
using FFTW
using Plots
using WAV, PlotlyJS

snd, sampFreq = wavread("input.wav")

N, _ = size(snd)
t = 0:1/(N-1):1;
s = snd[:,1]

y = fft(s)

y1 = copy(y)
for i = 1:N
    if abs(y1[i]) > 800
        y1[i] = 0
    end
end

s_new = real(ifft(y1))
wavwrite(s_new, "output1.wav", Fs = sampFreq)

y2 = copy(y)
for i = 1:N
    if abs(y2[i]) <  800
        y2[i] = 0
    end
end

s_new = real(ifft(y2))
wavwrite(s_new, "output2.wav", Fs = sampFreq)

sticks((abs.(y1)))
sticks!((abs.(y2)))

s1,k1 = wavread("output1.wav")
s2,k2 = wavread("output2.wav")

for i = 1:N
    s1[i] += s2[i]
end

wavwrite(s1, "output3.wav", Fs = sampFreq)
```

it's the code that reads file input.wav, next do fft on the sound, dividing it into two files output1 with only frequencies > 800 and output2 with frequencies < 800.

In next part I merge the two files into output3. I expected something similar to input, but what I get sounds terrible (I mean it sounds like input, but is quieter and with hum bigger than expected).

My question is on which part of a code I loose the most information about input and is it a way to improve it, to get as output3 something almost like input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to not understand what the fft (fast fourier transform) returns. It returns a vector of amplitudes, not frequencies. The vector's components correspond to a the amplitude of a sine wave at a frequency that you can find using the fftfreq() function, but be sure to provide the fftfreq() function with its second argument, your sampFreq variable.

To decompose the sound, then, you need to zero the vector components you do not want, based on what fftfreq() tells you the frequencies corresponding to the bins (vector postions in the vector returned by fft().

You will still see a big drop in sound quality with reversing the process with ifft, because the fft will basically average parts of the signal by splitting it into the frequency dimension's bins.

I suggest a tutorial on fft() before you fix your code further --  you can google several of these.